# Can we bypass entering kernel mode to execute system call code in assembly language?

Tags: assembly, linux-kernel, operating-system

I'm wondering that can we just copy system call code and drivers code  to our assembly program and use these code to manipulate hardware? Say wipe out the hard drive?

Could we copy code from kernel mode and use it to do anything we want? As in: can we just copy any code that runs in the kernel to user mode, and do the exact same as the kernel?

Is there any thing that can stop us from doing this?

Comment: Looking forward to any comment. Have lots of questions about kernels.

Comment: This is not possible due to memory protection.  The kernel is permitted by the CPU to directly access the hardware while your program is not.  It has to ask the kernel to do that for it.

Comment: Yup - by tbe time your user process thread/s get execution, assemby/binary/machine/whatever, it's too late - the OS has already set up the memory-management HARDWARE to prevent your process behaving badly.  Privileged instructions will not be executed and an attempt to do so will just generate a hardware interrupt to the OS memory manager kernel software.

Comment: One thing to note in general: assembly is not a magic thing.  It does not let you do anything you couldn't do from C.

Answer (score 4):

> can we just copy any code that run in kernel to user mode

No, you cannot. Kernel mode code has two main differences from user mode code that make it impossible to run in user space:

1. It uses privileged instructions (and privileged special registers) to communicate with hardware which are not available in userspace. If executed in userspace, such instructions will cause hardware exceptions and redirect control to a kernel exception handler that will kill your program for executing a forbidden instruction.

   This also answers your question:

   > Is there any thing that can stop us from doing this?

   Yes, *the processor itself* will stop you from doing this, and since the kernel has installed the appropriate exception handlers for such events, it will then act accordingly.
2. Even being able to execute those instructions, you would still need to access and manipulate data stored in kernel space, for example directory entries, page tables, task structures, etc. This data is completely invisible to any userspace program due to [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) isolation.

Comment: For the most part, it's the #2 from above that stops hardware access.  Most devices are controlled via memory mapped registers now, so if those registers where in the process's address space, then you could tell it to do things.  This is entirely possible, by using `mmap()` on `/dev/mem`, no privileged instructions required.  Of course the whole privileged instruction thing comes in play if a process wanted to change its address space without using the kernel.